# Improve server response time on Google PageSpeed Insight. Is it New?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have build a template and some site for client. I always give a concern about site loading time. I Google PageSpeed Insights is one of my main tool. Two days ago, i have mention something different. I found that many of my site page load is drop. And the PageSpeed rule that affect to that change is "**Improve server response time**". I never see this rule before.

I ask to my hosting service to know if is there any server issues, and he check it using GTmetrix. And he said that it just OK, he don't find any significant issues. I check it myself and see the Google PageSpeed Insights for the site is **different**.

Please take a look,

- This is pagespeed insight test result http://imm.io/123Ex
- and this is GTMetrix test result http://imm.io/123EV

Is **"Improve server response time"** is a new rule, and if it yes, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google just announced a "PageSpeed" service that you can use (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service), where you essentially host your site on their servers.

Using that would forever fix their viewing of your pagespeed, since they'd be viewing it from their own servers. Though who knows if it's faster than other CDN networks...

I'm sure it would considerably speed up the serving of your content though, since Google is all about making the internet faster.